# Make Visual Studio C++ project with missing references link OK

Tags: c++, visual-studio, solution

Context: Visual Studio 2019.

I have a suite of C++ projects that need to be compiled both into individual (plugin) DLLs, as well as be linked statically into a single application for testing purposes.  For this purpose I have created two sets of configurations; "Plugin" and "Test".  Under the "Plugin" configuration they compile and link into DLLs, while under the "Test" config they end up as static libs.  So far so good.

I have also added the test app project to this solution, which has a project reference to all of these plugin projects.  Under the "Plugin" config this test app project is just set to not be built.

But I also have a much smaller solution which has only a few plugin projects added to it.  My aim is to have a much quicker build cycle when working on the core framework of these plugins, while still being able to quickly test resulting binaries.  A small change there means all plugin projects need to be rebuilt, which takes a lot of time.  For the plugin config this works (each project generates it's own binary), but when building the test app project Visual Studio errors out about the project references to the projects missing from the solution.  The problem is that the test app project needs the whole list of project references when included in the full solution, but only a subset of the project references when included in the small solution.

Is there some workable setup I can use?  I could duplicate the test app project itself for this purpose, and give the copy less project references, but I'd rather not to avoid duplicate maintenance.  And I want to be free to just update the mix of plugin projects in the smaller solution, without having to update the project references as well.

### Addition

As an illustration: say we have plugin projects P1 to P9 (and 9 is an understatement here).  We also have the test app project T.  And we have two solutions containing these projects; one 'full' solution Sf containing all plugins as well as the test app, and one 'lite' solution Sl with only some of the plugins but also the test app.

```
Sf:
- P1
- ...
- P9
- T

Sl:
- P2
- P6
- T
```

Since project T needs to link in the static libs created by the P projects, it has a project reference to them.  So when managing project T in Sf I check each P project as a dependency.  However, since in solution Sl the same project T appears, and since these project dependencies are stored in project T and not in the solution Sf, project T finds itself in a solution in which not all projects it wants to link in are present.  And thus when building that solution, VS gives a link error on those missing projects.

What I'm interested in is what other solutions there are.  I can duplicate the T project and give each copy a separate list of dependencies, but then I'd have to keep both T's in sync.  I could also drop the dependencies and add them to the linker input setting of T, but that only moves the problem to another spot, plus it makes it harder to set up when new plugins arrive.

Comment: Can you just create a 'dummy' project (or even just a single source file) that has placeholder definitions for the missing references? Or are there so many that this would be unfeasible?

Comment: Oh, with references I didn't mean a C++ reference to variables, but actual project dependency references.  The ones from the menu "Project \ Add reference".  I'll update the post to reflect this better.

Comment: Do you mean to call a part of the dll? If so, it seems that there is no direct setting that can meet your needs. I suggest you that split the dll into several dlls.

Comment: @BarrnetChou: no, just as an all-or-nothing solution per plugin project.  So in my main solution I have all plugin projects present, and that either builds all plugin dlls, or build a test app with the functionality of all those dlls statically linked in.  But since rebuilding all plugins takes (quite some) time, I am searching for a solution (heh) in which I can have only a subset of the plugin projects present but still have the test app project in there as-is.  But since it has references to all those other projects too, it fails to link.

Comment: As an aside: each plugin project has a registration object inside it, which registers itself with a central list.  The test app in turn refers to the list to see which plugins there are.  So it's not that the test app is functionally bound to any individual plugin project; each plugin project derives from a common base and the test app just iterates over all known derived plugins.  Which poses another problem in itself in that these global static registration objects get optimized away by VS, but that's of later concern (and I also saw some solutions floating around for that too).

Comment: Could you provide an example? I really can't understand your problem description and needs. This seems to be a problem related to VS itself, so I recommend you to ask on [Microsoft DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: @BarrnetChou: I've added a schematic to the post making it a bit more clear what I want.  The funny thing is that in earlier VS versions this was genuinely possible (even in VS 2017 I think).  But time (and my license) has moved on so I'd rather not go back to VS 2017.  Maybe I could also use the 2019 GUI but make use of the 2017 toolchain, but to me that's not worth the hassle.

Comment: And I think im SOL here anyway :) so I think I'd best let this question rest.  Or indeed post it to Microsoft DC, and let them sort it out if it's a regression thing wrt 2017 or not, though having it working now instead of in VS 2022 would be better.

Comment: In my opinion, it is best to submit this issue to [Microsoft DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).